# Get "Missing expression after unary operator '-'" when I try to run a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

When I try to run following command

```
C:\Documents and Settings\BURE\My Documents\ibos\script>powershell.exe  -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden & 'C:\Documents and Settings\BURE\My Documents\ibos\script\files_from_nomad.ps1' 1
```

I get following error

```
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2
+ - <<<< WindowStyle Hidden
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

It works before, but not now?
Why?

What I try to do is to schadular a script:

```
schtasks /CREATE /RU BURE /SC MINUTE /TN files_to_nomad   /TR "powershell.exe  -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden & 'C:\Documents and Settings\BURE\My Documents\ibos\script\files_to_nomad.ps1' 1"
```

I have exact the same schedular on another computer.

Comment: Shouldn't the `&` be either escaped or quoted? `cmd` will otherwise take this as a command separator.

Comment: It don't solve it. It did works before to do so

Answer (score 3):

I get the same error when I try to execute your command (but with double quotes around `&` to `1`) on PowerShell 1.0.  1.0 doesn't support the WindowStyle parameter.  Is it possible you are developing this on 2.0 but then testing it out on a PowerShell 1.0 system?  Also, if you are running this from PowerShell 2.0 this will make the current window hidden.  Is that your intent?  You could fire the script off in another, hidden PowerShell window using Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden.

Comment: Yes, I want to hide the window. It was developed on 2.0 and I try to run it on the same machine.

Comment: On the machine it fails on, what info does $PSVersionTable return?

Comment: I check powershell's version. In powershell version 1.0, it had error.I try to install powershell 2.0. It's running now.

Answer (score 0):

put quotes around  `"-WindowStyle Hidden"`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the command should be quoted:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden "& 'C:\Docum...\script\files_from_nomad.ps1' 1"
```

Besides that - have you tried to remove `-WindowStyle Hidden`? What does it do then?

Comment: I get 
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2
+ - <<<< WindowStyle Hidden & 'C:\Docum...\script\files_from_nomad.ps1' 1

"-WindowStyle Hidden" hide the window

Comment: What is the whole command line that you run after the quoting I suggest? And does it work if you remove the `-WindowStyle Hidden`?

Comment: If I remove -WindowStyle Hidden the powershell shell start, but the script dont run

Answer (score 0):

arguments : -file "C:\Program Files\path\to\pcp\script.php"

Comment: Could you please add a little more context to this answer?